# Python could not generate the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I used the following code to generate a plot which shows pairs that are solution to a specific equation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(4.01,12,.01)
y = np.arange(6,18,.01)
for i_ind, i in enumerate(y):
    for j_ind, j in enumerate(x):
        k = 10/(6+j)
        if j == ((i**(1/k)-(i-6)**(1/k))/6)**(k/(1-k)):
            plt.scatter(i,j)
plt.show()
```

However, when I run the code nothing happens. Do you guys have any idea how can I solve this problem? In addition, are there any alternatives for plt.scatter to show pairs while they are connected by lines?

ps: i = j = 6 is a solution to the equation.

Comment: Your code never reaches `plt.scatter`, since the condition `j == <etc>` is never `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`j == ((i**(1/k)-(i-6)**(1/k))/6)**(k/(1-k))` is never `True` so there is nothing to plot. You can see that by adding a `print` statement within your `if` block. And you can also add `plt.scatter(0,0)` at the very end to confirm displaying graphs does work.

You should probably use a tolerance check instead like `abs(j - ((i**(1/k)-(i-6)**(1/k))/6)**(k/(1-k))) < 1e-3`. Or even better use a numerical solver, e.g. from `scipy`.

Comment: As an example the equation is true when j = i = 6.

Comment: Given numerical float errors `j` is never `6 exactly`: try to print `x[199]` with full precision you'll get `5.999999999999957`. Which leads to `5.999999999999996` for `((i**(1/k)-(i-6)**(1/k))/6)**(k/(1-k))`.